# value is not pass from view to controller using ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am performing an AJAX call using a function but my value did not pass through it.

```
 function GoToUpdatePage(currentID) {
       var SessionTegInfo = {};
       SessionTegInfo.StockCode = document.getElementById("stocktxt").checked;
       SessionTegInfo.StockCodeValue = document.getElementById("SearchValuestock").value;       
       SessionTegInfo.CurrentID = currentID;
       $.ajax({
           url: "@Url.Action("UpdateWithSessionStore", "MyMasterUpdate")",
           data: JSON.stringify(SessionTegInfo),
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function (data) {
           },
           error: function (data) {
           }
       });
    }
```

Here is my code from server side

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateWithSessionStore([FromBody] MySessionClass SessionTegInfo)
{
.....
return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyUpdateController", new { id = SessionTegInfo.CurrentID });
}
```

Here are my class details

```
 public class MySessionClass 
    {
        public string StockCode { get; set; }
        public string StockCodeValue { get; set; }       
        public string CurrentID { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried it without `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yes, tried but did not work

Comment: Why don't u put an alert to view the data before the Ajax is called to view  the data info.

Comment: @YatFeiLeong `console.log(SessionTegInfo);` Get all the data in console

Comment: Check the console log error. Right-click on the page and click `inspect`